# Checkbox is selected and not assigning a new value

Tags: php

No matter what is selected it is still assigning a value of 1 to all the checkboxes and not changing the selected checkbox to a value of 0. Here is the code that is correct from a syntax standpoint but defaults to 1 no matter what I do not see why its not changing the selected box value to '0'

```
//Correct answer variables
$chkBox1 = '1';
$chkBox2 = '1';
$chkBox3 = '1';
$chkBox4 = '1';
$chkBox5 = '1';

if (isset($_POST['chkBox1'])) {

if ($chkBox1 == 'chkBox1Selected') {
$chkBox1 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox1Selected logic


if (isset($_POST['chkBox2'])) {

if ($chkBox2 == 'chkBox2Selected') {
$chkBox2 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox2Selected logic


if (isset($_POST['chkBox3'])) {

if ($chkBox3 == 'chkBox3Selected') {
$chkBox3 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox3Selected logic
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` statements will never evaluate to `true`.

Take a look at one checkbox:

```
$chkBox1 = '1';

if (isset($_POST['chkBox1'])) {
    if ($chkBox1 == 'chkBox1Selected') {
        $chkBox1 = '0';
    }
}
```

`$chkBox1` is set to `'1'`, and it is never changed from that, so it never will be equal to `'chkBox1Selected'`.

That being said, you shouldn't have to worry about the value of the checkboxes, since **only checked checkboxes will be sent to the server**.

Theoretically, you could just do:

```
if (isset( $_POST['chkBox1'])) {
    $chkBox1 = '0';
}
```

However, if you want to read the value of the checkbox, you should be able to do this:

```
if (isset( $_POST['chkBox1'])) {
    if ($_POST['chkBox1'] == 'chkBox1Selected') {
        $chkBox1 = '0';
    }
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
if( isset( $_POST['chkBox1']) && ($_POST['chkBox1'] == 'chkBox1Selected')) {
        $chkBox1 = '0';
}
```

Comment: isn't that where I have $chkbox1=0 I'm stating that if the value attribute of the checkbox is 'chkBox1Selected' to then make it 0 instead of the default of 1?

Comment: No, it's not. I've updated my answer to show how to check the value of the checkbox.